# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I just saw that there is a similar post with the same title that mine. However, the scenario is different.

I've the following code on my view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>            
        @Html.ActionLink(modelItem => item.TrackingNumber.ToString(), "Details")
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    . . .
```

When I run my view I get the error as the title says. What I'm trying to achieve is to render the data that is fetch from the database and put it as a link.

Any clue how could I do that? Should I use a different html helper insted of the ActionLink?

Regards!

Comment: It needs to be `@Html.ActionLink(item.TrackingNumber.ToString(), "Details")` - you can use a lambda expression in `Html.ActionLink` - the first parameter is a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using

```
 @Html.ActionLink()
```

First see the definition of this HTML helper.It accepts string as the first parameter not the lamba expression.It is not strongly typed.

Use this

```
 @Html.ActionLink(item.TrackingNumber.ToString(), "Details")
```